# Vesta Panel Memcached Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached, vps, whmcs

I'm using for VPS server Vesta Control Panel, I install memcached then start but not working memcached library 
This error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in /home/admin/web/arayanbulurmus.com/public_html/application/libraries/memcached_library.php on line 120

http://prntscr.com/7rj8cs

Comment: this question answers look at the link http://www.servermom.org/how-to-build-lamp-server-on-centos-6-4/719/

Comment: Memcache and memcached are not the same thing.